# Membership Report (Detail) filter not applied when first run

Tags: civimember, civireport

The Membership Report (Detail) report returns *all* members, including delete ones. It seems the filter isn't applied until you click View Results.  Is this intentional, or a bug?  I see it with 5.15.2 under Joomla.

Comment: Have you saved a copy of the report with the filter you want and tried it that way?

Comment: Great, that seems to have solved it.